# Braintree Payment Transfer

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, braintree, stripe-connect

I am developing a C2C portal where seller will post their product and others can buy it. I have planned to use Braintree for payment process. Now once the payment is completed system will take commission and it should transfer the rest to seller.

I thought I could use ACH, but I cant find any solution or required document to transfer to seller account.

Note: I could achieve the same using Stripe Connect. The reason raising a question here is use the knowledge others having.

Comment: I recently implemented this split payment with Stripe, works super good and easy. But sorry, I don't have experience with Braintree.

Comment: @JørgenThe problem here I have is to hold the amount until the buyer validate the product. I have achieved it using stripe connect, but I need to find a way using Braintree.

Comment: Ah okay sorry can't help. Good luck!

Comment: No problem @Jørgen thank you.

Comment: Hey @MaathiYosi, have you checked this out? https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/create/php. It looks like you may set the transfer destination when onboarding a merchant: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/onboarding/php. I've never used these features, just reading the docs, but it seems very similar to Stripe Connect.

Comment: @GustavoStraube Yes, Marketplace is one of the option. But I have received update  from Braintree as Marketplace solution is unavailable for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Well, without having access to marketplace features, I'm afraid you won't be able to build a marketplace and do things such as transfers to sellers.

Comment: @GustavoStraube I have been advised to use HyperWallet by Braintree. But I am concerned about its reliability and cost.

Comment: @MaathiYosi I didn't know HyperWallet but checking their website I don't think it's a service "by Braintree". They're more like a competitor, I guess. Well, this is out of the scope of your original question, but if you're considering moving from Braintree, I would suggest using a reliable service like Stripe (with Connect), as you yourself mentioned before.

Comment: Is the problem that you can't notify the seller that a purchase has been made? Or register the purchase with the seller? Can really make sense. One option is to use webhooks

Comment: I would contact Braintree about Marketplace to see if they will give access to you.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of payments called Multiplexing payments.

**The best practice** is to let Braintree do it for you, read their document completely and contact them to help you with multiplexing payments.

**On the other hand** if you want to make the seller payment After the money is cleared from Braintree, The ACH possibility should be done bank account which the money will be transferred to.

Answer (score 1):

use the recommended packages by laravel it's better and more safely :

Stripe

Mollie

as you know you can find them in the official website for laravel under the official packages section